# How to make an adjustable image container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

The image should cover when the height of the container is larger than image but in varying coverage. Using boxfill cover on a sliverappbar doesn't vary the image dimensions.

```
SliverAppBar(
      title: Text('SliverAppBar'),
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      expandedHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        background:
            Image.asset('assets/caesar-salad.png', fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
    ),
```

The images below is the transition i hope to achieve, but with the code above, the image dimension remains the same and doesnt resize.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

solved it by;

```
 flexibleSpace: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
              image: ExactAssetImage('assets/caesar-salad.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover),
        ),
      ),
```